# Select boundaries of uv islands in 3d viewport

Tags: python, scripting, uv, selection-tools

I need to select edges of all uv boundaries similar to how i can select all seam\sharp edges with `shift-g` menu.
I was thinking of solution where you (using python) iterate through all vertices(or edges) and select only those that have more than one projection in uv space.
Can you help me with API or other solution?
p.s. i need this to get rid of sharp edges that somehow appeared inside of my uv islands

Answer (score 1):

as a workaround found this option, not a perfect solution if you already have edges marked as seams and you need them. hope to see the proper answer

[image]